# Room, storing Map<String, List<String> or many to many relation

Tags: android, dictionary, many-to-many, android-sqlite, android-room

Currently I have `Contact` class looking as

```
package com.example.courseproject;

import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "contact_table")
public class Contact {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Map<String, List<String>> contacts; //Type, Values. Example { "email": {"email_1", "email_2"}}

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, Map<String, List<String>> contacts) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

and on line 20 (the map declaration) it says

```
...\Contact.java:20: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private Map<String, List<String>> contacts; //Type, Values. Example { "email": {"email_1", "email_2"}}
```

The idea is to make a Phonebook, which can store (of course) multiple "people" and each can have different contact (and different quantity of them).

Is it okay to be done with the map? If so can I simply use JSON lib for that thing? If not what would you suggest?

As far as I know there should be "table" for many to many relation between the  "contacts" field and Contact. I really like the idea of the JSON because its simple and fast but I know it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Map as variable to be stored in database. 
Dont set ID - Room will auto generate it for You. As tip from Android Studio says 
You can use TypeConverter for map:
[Room TypeConverter for map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912855/room-typeconverter-for-map)